# Define a custom property to bind to

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

Is it possible to bind the items of the control within the user control to a property whose name is specified via binding?

Something like this, but without the error produced:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource='{Binding Path=CheckListItems, ElementName=Root}'>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- What should I put below to replace the inner binding? -->
                <CheckBox Content='{Binding Path={Binding Path=ItemPropertyName, ElementName=Root}, Mode=OneTime}' />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Where

- `CheckListItems` (DP) is a collection of items `(IList<SomeCustomContainerType>)`
- `ItemPropertyName` (DP) is the name of the property within the `SomeCustomContainerType` that should be displayed as a check box text
- `Root` is the name of the User Control

The exception in this case is (expectedly) as following:

```
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'.
A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

Basically I want to pass the property name whose text should be displayed in a checkbox somehow from outside. It doesn't have to be bindable, but should be settable from the XAML consuming the user control.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)?

[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3b40e47d-8e65-40ab-a921-748ab67f2609) is an example of how to use it

try this, and see if it works:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CheckListItems, ElementName=Root}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ItemPropertyName, ElementName=Root}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- What should I put below to replace the inner binding? -->
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But DisplayMemberPath will use the same property for each in the List. I think he wants to use another property for each item. I do not support the architecture, but it is possible.

Comment: @Catfisherman added codesample, please see if it works for you. if I understood you right, then this is the way to go

Comment: @Markus: the codesample would work if you removed the inner binding from the checkbox content attribute and put the default path there (the dot) and created templated for each of the custom types. That would be fine, I'll use it as a backup solution (due to architecture/design complications) in case I won't find a better solution. Anyways, a possible solution.

Comment: @Catfisherman whoops, excuse me, that was a typo... stupid copy/paste... also, you probably won't really get a better solution, as this is exactly what DisplayMemberPath is for

Comment: @Markus: I meant that either I will put a data template (which creates the checkbox) or a DisplayMemberPath (which in fact displays a text). After I try to put this code the following error emerges: "Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate." I suppose I would either use data templates for every custom container within the list or need to find another solution. I would like to avoid the former one because I might not know what user container type will be used.

Comment: @Catfisherman, OK I see, I thought this was possible. Have you tried if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath.aspx) fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use a ValueConverter with a ConverterParameter as the name of the Property. In the ValueConverter implementation you could load the the Value with Reflection.

the converter could look something like that:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
public class ReflectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            Type type = value.GetType();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty (parameter.ToString());
            return prop.GetValue(value, null);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- add errorhandling...

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll give it a try, it might work ;) You don't have to code the example.

Comment: OK, I'm stuck. How do I load the ConverterParameter from the Dependency Property? I can't put binding here.

Comment: i just wanted to try it too, i edited the code example in the answer

Comment: hmm sorry, it wont really work. didnt think about that the CommandParameter cant be bound neither...

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your line with this:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding ItemPropertyName}" />
```

Comment: This would bind the content to the ItemPropertyName dependency property. I want to bind to a DP whose name is specified by another DP.